# How to write the recurrence relation of a pseudocode?

Tags: algorithm, math, recursion, time-complexity, big-o

```
Foo(A,f,l) 
**Precondition: A[f ...l] is an array of integers, f,l are two naturals ≥ 1 with f ≤ l. 
if (f = l) then 
     return A[f]
else 
     m ← floor of((f+l)/2) 
     return min(Foo(A,f,m), Foo(A,m + 1,l)) 
end if
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think this code returns the smallest integer of the array. But how do I figure out what the recurrence relation that describe the time complexity in terms of array A? Could you please guide me to the solution so I can understand? I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: Take some example values for A, f, l and draw what calls are made, i.e, the full recurrence. You’ll see that in each pass, the search space is halved. The complexity is logarithmic.

Comment: With that precondition `f <= l`, you can't ensure it is achieved in your internal calls. Also, it seems to be a useless precondition, maybe you should delete it. You can neither ensure that `m >= 1`

Comment: Look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it)

Comment: Let `n` be the size of the array so `n = l - f + 1`. `T(1) = 1`, so what's `T(n)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recurrence relation we can recover from the structure of the pseudocode. We can let `T(n)` represent the time taken by the algorithm as a function of the input size. For `n = 1`, the time is constant, say `T(1) = a`. Our question now is for larger `n`, how can we express `T(n)`?

We will be in the `else` clause for `n > 1`. We do some extra work - let's call it `b` - and then call the function twice, once for an input of size `floor(n/2)` and once for an input of size `ceiling(n/2)`. So we can write this part of the recursion as `T(n) = b + T(floor(n/2)) + T(ceiling(n/2))`. We can now write out some terms.

```
n    T(n)
1    a
2    b + a + a = b + 2a
3    b + b + 2a + a = 2b + 3a
4    b + b + 2a + b + 2a = 3b + 4a
5    b + b + 2a + 2b + 3a = 4b + 5a
...  ...
k    = (k-1)b + (k)a = kb - b + ka = k(a + b) - b
```

We find a guess that `T(n) = (a + b)n - b` for some constants `a` and `b` that depend upon the cost of amounts of work we might take as constant (note that computing `(f + l) / 2` is not really constant in terms of `n`, but it will not change our analysis). We can prove this using mathematical induction:

1. `T(1) = a = (a + b)(1) - b` is right;
2. Assume that `T(n) = (a + b)n - b` for all `n <= k`.
3. Does `T(k + 1) = (a + b)(k + 1) - b` hold? Remember that `T(k + 1) = b + T(floor((k+1)/2)) + T(ceiling((k+1)/2)`. Suppose `k+1` is even and `m = (k+1)/2`. Then T(k+1) = b + 2T(m) = b + 2[(a + b)(m) - b] = b + 2(m)(a+b) - 2b = (2m)(a+b) - b = (k+1)(a+b) - b`, as required. The case where`k + 1` is odd is left as an exercise.

This is linear.

Answer (score -1):

You're right. It returns the smallest integer of the array.

And the complexity is

```
O(nlog(n)); n = size of the array
```

`Explanation:` In each call, you are breaking the array into two equal parts which calls up to `f=l`. It calls the function `O(log(n))` times for each number in the array. So, total complexity is `O(nlog(n))`